# jQuery call function on input change by event

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a page which loads an external js and on the page I've got a function `called calculate_totals()`. What I want is to call the function `calculate_totals()` from a function in the external js.

This is a piece of JavaScript which loads in an external js

```js
function selectItemMouse(thisVar)
{   
    var searchValue = thisVar.attr('data-name');
    thisVar.parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.list').val(searchValue);
    
    
    //alert(thisVar.parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('input').focus());
    
    thisVar.children().children().each(function()
    {
        var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var value = $(this).attr('data-name');
        
        //This change the input of my form
        $(thisVar).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children('.'+dataId).val(value);
    });
    
    $('.customerResults').hide();
    calculate_totals();     
}
```

Comment: How is the value changed - by user typing, or by code?

Comment: Not clear why can't you show that alert after you update a value in that function you shown to us. Basically, there is no "change" event for value changed with JS. You need to trigger it somehow. Or you may use setInterval to check value each, for instance, 100ms and fire alert when it is changed.

Comment: `What I want is to call the function calculate_totals() from a function in the external js.` And what is a problem? I see you are calling it at the end of your function. And it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on commenting  session:
calculate_totals is defined inside of `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Because of that is not seen outside it. Basically, it is visible inside  `$(document).ready(function(){});` only. Just move it outside it. Now it will became global and visible anywhere.

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function calculate_totals() {} // this function is visible inside of a ready function only
  ///..... other code here
});
```

use:

```
function calculate_totals() {} // now it is a part of global context
$(document).ready(function(){
  ///..... other code here   
});
```

After that you should have it available inside selectItemMouse and any other place.

Besides, I would think on updating your code.

```
thisVar.parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.list').val(searchValue);
```

usage of such chains is not flexible. Just you will wrap thisVar element with some other element - you will need to update your JS code.

Take a look at [`.parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). For instance, you may change a line above like this:

```
thisVar.closest(".class_common_parent").children('.list').val(searchValue);
```

Where `.class_common_parent` is a class of an element which you take using `parent().parent().parent().parent().`

Comment: Take a look at updated answer. There is some advice about improving your code. That is JFYI.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a listener for a change on the input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input').change(function(){
        alert("alert here");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes but I want to detect it immediately and not when i lose the focus of that input.

Comment: Then you can use a keydown: `$('#input').keydown(function(){ alert(); });`

Comment: Can i use keydown when the value is set by function and not by typing?

Comment: no, that's only if a user has inputted anything. If you are changing the value through a function, then you can just trigger the alert after you have changed the value... `.val(value).done(function(){ });`

Comment: keydown, change and other events are not fired if you update a value with JS. You may trigger them manually, but than I see no difference between triggering an event and showing an alert directly from your function.

Comment: @FAngel I forgot to mention that I also want to call another function when the input has changed. That function is not in the same js but on the page itself where the external js is loaded...

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen not clear what is the problem. Just call it after you update a value. There is no difference if it is in another file or not, is it a part of JS file or inline script. jQuery is in another external file, but you still can use it.

Comment: @FAngel I tried but it doesnt do anything. In my console I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate_totals is not defined

Comment: Well, that is a different question. How it is defined? Is it a part of some other object? Possibly it is just hidden somehow. Possibly you should show how that calcilate_totals is defined.

Comment: The function calculate_totals() is in the  $(document).ready(function(){});